# build jar file from a spring project with foreign database connection

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I'm trying to build my Spring boot project to a JAR file.in my project, I used a local MySQL database to store my data but now my project is finished and is ready to launch it on a Linux server but when I change the MySQL connection info from application.properties the maven cant package the project and I'm getting this error

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:319) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:835) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:455) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:240) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:207) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar:8.0.13]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:136) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:369) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:198) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:467) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:541) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:151) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:115) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:78) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

and this is my maven pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>TransApplication</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>test</name>
<description>test</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <start-class>com.trans.co.TransApplication.TransApplication</start-class>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>logging-interceptor</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.22</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>package.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

my only problem is a simple change I want to change my connection info on the server

Comment: No you don't want to change that. Instead when running use a different `application.properties` or pass the properties as parameters.

Comment: @M.Deinum what do you mean with "Instead when running use a different " ? like change the application properties on the JAR file?

Comment: Is the server up and does it have the identical production database running? With regards to what @M.Deinum is suggesting, look into profiles within Spring. Your final set up should be `application-dev.properties` and `application-prd.properties` as an example of two properties files for two profiles.

Comment: @EdwinDiaz-Mendez both have the same version of MySQL installed

Comment: Most companies deal with this problem by either not including the properties in the jar, but keeping it outside the jar, or deploying it in a way where properties are either replaced (or overridden by a subset) by an external properties file, a configuration server or something else to manage properties. You normally don't recompile for different deploys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comment this //@SpringBootTest on the Test class  of your project

[image]

Comment: when you try to build a maven app, Maven will run the tests and in the test, Spring app need to connect to the database and this is why you can't build a app without a database connection

Answer (score 0):

From your description

> the maven cant package the project

This suggests that the Spring Boot Uber Jar is not being packaged as the test phase is failing in your Maven lifecycle.  Generally speaking, the Boot Jar should be packaged/assembled before deploying to your server, thus you should have no concerns for tests failing.

If you are building this on a server for the propose of producing your Boot Jar artifact from there, then that suggests that the datasource configuration you have defined is not applicable or correct in that environment.  You will either need to skip the tests requiring the local datasource, or provide a datasource that will allow your tests to succeed.

Spring Boot provides a robust configuration management system that can be adjusted based on environmental or even run by run contexts.  In fact, you are already using it and are set to go with it based on your description that you are changing the `application.properties` file.

High level information is detailed [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).  In particular, note the section describing the order the property sources are evaluated, as that gives you the power you need to adapt the properties depending on your deployment situation.

There are many options for you to proceed with, but generally speaking I have my development teams configure the `application.properties` file built into the jar (from the main resource sourceset by default) to work on default development environments.  Developers can also place an `application.properties` file in the working directory of their development environment to override these settings based on their development environments.  Properties can also be provided in the same fashion on build systems, or servers.  It also is convenient to define them via environment variables, or via [profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) which can define a large set of them based on the active profiles configuration property.  Large/expansive infrastructure can also benefit from [Spring Cloud Config](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-config) simplifying this management even greater.